# .NET Framework API Swashbuckle (Swagger) shows all params on iisexpress in dev but on prod IIS Server 2019 not showing all params

Tags: c#, asp.net, swashbuckle

I have deployed it to IIS v11 on Windows Server 2019. The API itself works, it is a Web API not on .NET Core. Swashbuckle shows only 1 param in the deployed state.

It is a configuration of some sort - but which one?

This is the API:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("endCitrixOnPremSession/{broker}/{uid}")]
public bool endCitrixOnPremSession(string broker, int uid)
```

The first screenshot is the localhost debugging IISexpress.

[image: this is the iisexpress localhost]

This screenshot is running on IIS it is not picking up the whole url

[image: This is IIS]

Comment: Also, the UID case has changed.  What Swashbuckle configuration do you have in startup.cs? Are you using some sort of obfuscation tool in production?

Comment: there is no startup.cs.  this is not core.  net 4.8 framework only

Comment: OK, so how are you configuring Swashbuckle?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. 100% a misconfig of my iis server. Solution was obfuscated by me, looking for answers in the wrong rabbit whole.  Path in IIS was set to wrong drive.